# how can I create a table from a database row?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate

with Hibernate commands, it's possible create table from result of row?

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS (SELECT * FROM old_table);
```

Comment: same as normal sql

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to create a materialized view, like so:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW new_table AS SELECT * FROM old_table;
```

[Source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html)

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to do it.

1)Creating table will require to link source base POJO(old table) into new POJO(new table) (with settrs and getters)

2)Create new table entity (with `@Table`) and use native sql query to copy data

```java
  .createNativeQuery( "INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table" )
  .executeUpdate();
```